# Redis mass insert not inserting everything

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cli

I'm trying to use redis massinsert over network with a 1.8gb file. It has about 6,000,000 entries, but only 900,000 are being added. Any reason for this?

```
cat massinsert.txt | redis-cli -h **myaddress** --pipe
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no duplicates? Maybe most of them overwrite each other?

Comment: No duplicates. Its all original data and I'm loading it to an empty cache, so I dont see any reason why everything wouldn't be inserted. When doing it more traditionally through python with pipelines, I get the correct number